# Error:(6) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an error with this code and I don't know how to fix it. Hope you guys can helpe me.
The error is in: android:iconTint="@android:color/white". The error is: Error:(6) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Menu" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Winkelmandje" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Bestellingen" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Afmelden" />

</group>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.your.packagename"
```

Comment: This gives an other error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix